# Хрупкость композиции при реализации операторов с учетом гарантии исключений

Tags: c++, исключения, композиция

Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю следующее.

У меня есть тип `A`. Предположим, что я хочу реализовать для такого типа оператор `A& operator=(const A& a)` со строгой гарантией относительно исключений. То есть, в случае отказа, оператор исключение кидает, но объект типа `A` остается в исходном состоянии.

Проблема - тип `A` содержит много полей, которые в свою очередь состоят из других полей, и где-то там внутри есть поле типа `Z`. Тысячи лет тип `Z` обеспечивал строгую гарантию относительно исключений своего оператора `Z& operator=(const Z& z)`, но вот одним ужасным днем эта гарантия была разрушена, и никто этого не увидел.

Вопросы следующие.

1. Действительно композиция настолько хрупка?
2. Как обнаружить, что поле типа `Z` стало нарушать гарантии того, что в рамках выполнения оператора `A& operator=(const A& a)` во всех цепочках операций обеспечивается строгая гарантия исключений?
3. Можно ли побороть эту хрупкость, если вместо композиции значений уйти в сторону композиции указателей (умных)? Ведь в таком случае объекты можно копировать путем вызова метода `Type::Uptr Type::Clone() const`. Перемещение реализовать еще проще - достаточно поменять значение указателя. Мне кажется, что это намного проще анализировать и отслеживать, но уверенности у меня в этом нет.

Comment: `Z& operator=(Z&& z)`? Не `Z& operator=(const Z& z)`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, все верно. Несколько раз упрощал вопрос, чтобы совсем уж людей не запутывать. И остался рудимент. Спасибо.

Comment: (2) - Делать тесты, а при обнаружении такого изменения - ругать авторов `Z`? Еще, вижу вариант не зависеть от гарантий на `operator=` полей - делать свой `operator=` на copy&swap.

Comment: оператор `A& operator=(const A& a)` работает с константной ссылкой. Ему сложно повредить объект внутри себя (если конечно кто то с mutable или const_cast не побаловался, но тут уже совсем другая история).

Comment: @KoVadim Я так понимаю, речь не про параметр, а про `this`, который он может оставить в наполовину измененном состоянии.

Comment: ну тогда человечество уже давно придумало решения - [swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: swap не поможет, если в Z нарушена гарантия в swap. Хотя согласен, что чтобы  нарушить гарантию в swap надо наделать глупых ошибок.

Comment: полностью защитится вряд ли получится. Но обеспечить хорошую гарантию можно. Хочется супер контроля - пишите код сами (хотя не факт, что сделаете лучше или быстрее).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы правы: умный указатель даёт гарантию даже не опираясь на гарантии полей. Сам класс `A` с указателем сохраняет тот же интерфейс что и реализация без указателя:

```
class A {
public:
    A& operator=(const A& a) {
        impl.reset(new Impl(*a.impl));
        return *this;
    }
private:
    struct Impl {
        Z z;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
};
```